# Uwsgi blocked when communicate with nginx

Tags: tcp, nginx, uwsgi

everyone, recent days i meet a strange problem which really make me nuts.

I am using nginx + uwsgi + django to deploy a site in production .The site have about 300million requests each day and the maximun concurrency is 4000 per second, I have 4 nginx in front and 6 uwsgi in backend, nignx communicat with uwsgi via tcp.

It has performed well for a few monthes. But some day uwsgi suddenly do not work. it throws messages below:

HARAKIRI: --- uWSGI worker 72 (pid: 23094) WAS managing request /2/article/v2/stream/?detail=1&image=1&count=20&max_behot_time=1358697136&latitude=39.914651254102&longitude=116.45855261839&city=&device_platform=android&channel=hiapk&version_code=220&app_name=news_article&openudid=474604a56e33a44f&uuid=353769056450763&os_api=16&device_type=GT-N7100&os_version=4.1.1 since Mon Jan 21 23:07:51 2013 ---

From the message above it seems uwsgi kill itself due to there is a long request in django app. But i check my app view time and debug, 
I am sure that my app is quite fast(about 100ms handler a request).

To my surprise, i find nginx throws a lot of connecting time out to uwsgi, because of uwsgi killing itself repeatedly and the queue is full.

So i strace the uwsgi process, I find uwsgi blocked at write system call until it kill itseslf:

writev(8, [{"HTTP/1.1", 8}, {" ", 1}, {"200 OK", 6}, {"\r\n", 2}, {"Vary", 4}, {": ", 2}, {"Cookie", 6}, {"\r\n", 2}, {"Content-Type", 12}, {": ", 2}, {"text/html; charset=utf-8", 24}, {"\r\n", 2}, {"\r\n", 2}], 13) = 73

write(8, "{\"has_more\": true, \"message\": \"s"..., 24005

In my understanding， uwsgi use Nonblocking mode in tcp which will never blocked. I google a long time and have many tries, but it does none help.

At last, I change my deploy mod, I use 4 nginx listen 80 port in the front and use http_proxy to 6 nginx port 81, the nginx 81 port communicate vai unix file sock with uwsgi。After this try, the uwsgi never blocked and all is OK.

Who can tell me that why uwsgi blocked at write syscall which i think should never happen ? Or in what case uwsgi will be blocked when communite with nginx via tcp ?

Much thanks